# Excel.Worksheet.UsedRange unequal on different machines

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am parsing the same Excel file in c# 4.0 on two different machines.
I get different values for **xlWorkSheet.UsedRange** on each machine.

My program targets the same interop dll on both machines:

-Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
-Version: 12.0.0.0
-Runtime Version: v1.1.4322

***Machine A***

- Windows Server 2003 R2
- Excel 2007 (12.0.4518.1014)

***Machine B***

- Windows XP 2002 SP3
- Excel 2007 (12.0.4518.1014)

Column A of my excel worksheet is empty.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = GetWorkSheet();
```

On machine A

```
((dynamic)xlWorkSheet.UsedRange).Column = 2
```

On machine B

```
((dynamic)xlWorkSheet.UsedRange).Column = 1
```

Any idea what may be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: what are the runtime versions of Excel / Windows on those machines exactly ?

Comment: I've updated the question with this info.  Thanks

Comment: thanks for the update... which basically means that the Excel file (if it is bit by bit 100% identical!) itself is rather strange (might even be slightly corrupt) which in turn means microsoft is the only one who can help there...

Comment: yes, the files are bit-by-bit identical

Comment: then ask MS (if you have a support contract that is).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately we do not have an MS support contract

Comment: this goes far beyond what SO can help with...